# Please explain this expression

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am trying to write a letter in russian. I am new to this language.

"...,юлди всё ещё посылают телеграммы своим родственникам друзьям".

What does this mean...my guess is "..their relatives and friends" but I am a little uncertain about the conjugation. Is it because the chain of words is controlled by a feminine noun that in dative and that the reason why the words ends in -им -ам and -ям?

Comment: Add some context please. Without the context your phrase may mean "... to someone's relatives and friends", btw you missed "и" in your russian phrase.

Comment: Updated the sentence you so you can see the context. I have not written the sentence. It comes out of a A2 level textbook that was written in UK EN and then translated into my language. Many times there are so many typos and missing parts that one gets confused. The A1 book was a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is missing between the second and the third word in the expression.

> "...своим родственникам друзьям"

is a phrase that has two nouns (родственникам, друзьям) and one (reflexive possessive) pronoun which you correctly identified.

The case is Dative, which answers the question "to whom" or "for whom" (not a simple translation of course, in Russian it's "кому").  All words are in the dative case, as if you "give" them something.

As Roman points out, a conjunction 'и' might be missing, or a comma (to make it

> "...своим родственникам и друзьям"
>   "...своим родственникам, друзьям"

Answer (score 0):

Two consecutive datives have no sense. Should be a comma or "and" between them, just like in English.

*Свой* is a reflexive pronoun. It may mean *my*, *your*, *their* or whatever depending on context.

Answer (score 0):

So, according to the context:

> "... **люди** всё ещё посылают телеграммы своим родственникам **и** друзьям"

It may be translated as "**...people still send telegrams to their relatives and friends.**"